# Thousands of texture parts generated when importing .skp file in Cinema4D

Tags: texture, mac, import, cinema4d, sketchup

Im trying to import a bunch of sketchup files into Cinema4D (R20). Some of them generate thousands of JPG's when i drag them into Cinema.

This one for example generated over 15'000 .jpg files before i cancelled the import:
https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/cd29cdb2-ea99-49c0-a85c-2cf3234ac3b4/Flowers-hight-poly-maps-vray-ready-004

The best thing is, those are not even used in Cinema4D. Only one of them or an additional normal map texture.

This is what part of the folder looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone ran into this issue? Is there a workaround?